# I need help to connection websocket in python3

Tags: python, websocket

I try connect to websocket but i have error:

> server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 403

but when i try in website it's run like this website:

http://www.epetool.com/websocket/

the code in python 3.9:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def handler(websocket):

   while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        print(message)

async def main():
    url = "wss://io.dexscreener.com/dex/screener/pairs/h6/1?rankBy[key]=volume&rankBy[order]=desc&filters[buys][h1][min]=100&filters[sells][h1][min]=100&filters[liquidity][min]=500&filters[pairAge][max]=1&filters[chainIds][0]=bsc"
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        await handler(ws)
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever



if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```